# Reading txt file line by line than than write all lines to the RichTextBox

Tags: c#

when i click to button it'll take these links from c:\text.txt file and it will write into   my richtextbox

in my text.txt:

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

(there is no empty rows between links)

after that i want to call that links line by line into my other button to parse its html codes and write to other richtextbox

here is my parse button code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = KaynakKodunuCek("http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lale");
        // <p ... > </p> tagları arasını alıyor.(taglar dahil)
        Regex regex = new Regex("<p[^>]*>.*?</p>");
        string gelen = s;
        string inside = null;
        Match match = regex.Match(gelen);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            inside = match.Value;
            richTextBox3.Text = inside;
        }
        string outputStr = "";
        foreach (Match ItemMatch in regex.Matches(gelen))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ItemMatch);
            inside = ItemMatch.Value;
            //boşluk bırakıp alt satıra yazıyor 
            outputStr += inside + "\r\n";
        }
        richTextBox3.Text = outputStr;
    }
```

here i want to call links string s = KaynakKodunuCek("here");

Or should i use listbox instead of richtextbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `listBox` would be better.But if you want to do it with `richTexBox` you can use this:

```
string[] links = richTextBox2.Text.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

for(int i=0;i<links.Length;i++)
{  
  string s = KaynakKodunuCek(links[i]);  
  ...
}
```